# Inorder Traversal with Recursion?

Tags: java, recursion

I have just started learning about tree traversal and I'm having a hard time understanding this code for a in-order tree traversal:

```
class tree {
   String data;
   tree left;
   tree right;
}

void inorder (tree root) {
   if (root == null) return;
   inorder (root.left);
   out.printf ("%s%n", root.data);
   inorder (root.right);
}
```

I dont understand that, once root != null, then won't program execution keep recursively calling line 2 of the in order method? and that won't lead to execution of print statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code traverses the tree until it hits a root that isn't set – i.e. `left` or `right` being `null`. If this happens, the current executon of `inorder` exits (prematurely, you might say) by calling `return`.

When using `return`, no matter where in a method, the method will terminate, so the following lines are not being executed.

---

Consider the tree

[image: Simple binary tree]

To represent this, you could create a structure like

```
Tree node4 = new Tree("Node 4", null, null);
Tree node5 = new Tree("Node 5", null, null);
Tree node2 = new Tree("Node 2", node4, node5);
Tree node6 = new Tree("Node 6", null, null);
Tree node7 = new Tree("Node 7", null, null);
Tree node3 = new Tree("Node 3", node6, node7);
Tree root  = new Tree("Root", node2, node3);
```

When calling `inorder` on root, you'd get:

> Node 4
>   Node 2
>   Node 5
>   Root
>   Node 6
>   Node 3
>   Node 7

Note that I updated `Tree` to have a constructor (and also uppercased it, since classes should being with a capital letter).

```
public Tree(String data, Tree left, Tree right) {
    this.data = data;
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain this line by line?

Comment: @YoshiK Which part don't you understand? Try creating an example tree of trees and see.

Answer (score 0):

`I dont understand that, once root != null, then won't program execution keep recursively calling line 2 of the in order method?`

That is correct, but the key to understanding what's going on is to realize that you're passing in the left child into the method call. At some point, the current node (ie: root) will be null because the previous node has no more `left` children.

You need to pay attention to what values are being passed around.

As for when the print statement is being executed, the code is still executed from top to bottom.

For example, consider the following possible sequence of events:

```
root != null
call in_order(left)
  root != null
  call in_order(left)
    root == null
    return
  print root.data
  call in_order(right)
    root == null
    return
  # done
print root.data
call in_order(right)
   root == null
   return
# done
```

When the method calls itself, it doesn't just stop executing. It will execute the called method as usual, and once the method returns, it will continue from where it left off.

Comment: Thank you! But what I was trying to understand was that when is the printf statement being executed?

Comment: Added some more info.

Answer (score 0):

// Java

private static ArrayList inOrder(HuffTree currentObject, ArrayList byteSequence) {

```
    if (currentObject != null) {
        inOrder(currentObject.child0, byteSequence);
        if (!(currentObject.filling == null)) byteSequence.add(currentObject.filling);
        inOrder(currentObject.child1, byteSequence);
    }
    return byteSequence;
}
```

}

// class code here

import java.util.Objects;

/**

- Huffman tree as class
  */

class HuffTree implements Comparable {

```
// element filling
Byte filling;
// element repeats
int repeats;
// zero child
HuffTree child0;
// child 1
HuffTree child1;

/**
 * constructor for tree fathers and leaves
 */
public HuffTree(Byte filling, int repeats, HuffTree child0, HuffTree child1) {
    // father filling
    this.filling = filling;
    // father repeats
    this.repeats = repeats;
    // zero child
    this.child0 = child0;
    // child 1
    this.child1 = child1;
}

/**
 * finding difference between our tree's items
 */
@Override
public int compareTo(HuffTree currentByte) {
    return currentByte.repeats - repeats;
}


/**
 * take byte code as a string by recursive three search in depth
 */
public String getCodeForByte(Byte currentByte, String wayToFather) {
    // there is 4 cases:
    if (!Objects.equals(filling, currentByte)) {
        // case 1 - zero child found
        if (child0 != null) {
            // recursive code add for zero child
            String currentWay = child0.getCodeForByte(currentByte, wayToFather + "0");
            // return temporary string
            if (currentWay != null) return currentWay;
        }
        // case 2 - child 1 found. recursive code add for child 1. return temporary string
        if (child1 != null) return child1.getCodeForByte(currentByte, wayToFather + "1");
    }
    // case 3 - correct leaf found. return correct code
    if (Objects.equals(filling, currentByte)) return wayToFather;
    // case 4 - wrong leaf found. return null
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: May you please format your code and add a bit of explaination? Thank you!