# Binary Search Tree - PrintInOrder();

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

In my BST templated class, there is a `PrintInOrder()` function that takes no parameter.

```
void BST<Type>::printInOrder() const{}
```

I saw some functions and all of them take a `Node*` to root as a parameter, which makes sense.

How can I make a recursion to print all the values in order using the cited function?

**Code:**

```
/* I don't know if it's gonna help, but this is my class */

struct Node
{
    Type m_data;
    Node *m_left, *m_right;

    Node(const Type& _data) : m_data(_data), m_left(nullptr), m_right(nullptr) {}
};

Node* m_root;
int m_size;

public:
    BST();
    ~BST();
    BST& operator=(const BST& that);
    BST(const BST& that);;
    void insert(const Type& v);
    bool findAndRemove(const Type& v);
    bool find(const Type& v) const;
    void clear();
    void printInOrder() const;
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inorder Traversal with Recursion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034335/inorder-traversal-with-recursion)

Comment: His function passes a root as parameter. I'm trying to figure out a function that takes no parameter

Answer (score 0):

Just let the `printInOrder` function call a helper function that has a node pointer argument.

To limit the scope of the helper function it can be e.g.

- a private `static` member of the `BST` class, or
- a namespace scope free function in a namespace called `impl` or `detail` or such (convention for private implementation parts), or even
- a static function in a class internally in the `printInOrder` function.

Of course, instead of implementing the functionality with recursion you can just maintain an explicit stack and use an iterative solution, in which case you don't need a helper function.

General advice: you can avoid troublesome inadvertent text substitutions, as well as avoiding giving the impression of shouting, by reserving all uppercase names for macros. This is a common C++ convention.